# xsl How do I total the sum of one particular type of element based on an attribute from a different element

Tags: xslt, xpath

Given the following xml:

```
<orders>
    <order>
        <productName quantity="10">Blender</productName>
        <total price="20">200</total>
    </order>
    <order>
        <productName quantity="2">Computer</productName>
        <total price="1000">2000</total>
    </order>
    <order>
        <productName quantity="3">Scanner</productName>
        <total price="800">2400</total>
    </order>
</orders>
```

I would like to calculate the sum of all orders where quantity is greater than 2.  After hours and hours of trying, I finally give up. This is one of the solutions I have come up with (which is of course not working, returns 0):

xsl:value-of select="sum(order/productName[@quantity>2]/total)"

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sum(order[productName[@quantity>2]]/total)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Martin.  It worked. However, I had to precede order with '//' as in: "sum(//order[productName[@quantity>2]]/total)" for it to work. It'd be great to know why this had to be done.  I mean, I thought just the nodename should do the trick, but apparently not quite so.

Comment: Well, your original code snippet did not show any context but for a simple and direct `sum(order....)`, as you had it, I assumed a matching template `<xsl:template match="orders"><xsl:value-of select="sum(order[productName[@quantity>2]]/total)"/></xsl:template>`.